# Createjs: Adding mouseover to containers slowsdown FPS

Tags: javascript, createjs

Link 1 -  http://horebmultimedia.com/Sam3/
Link 2 -  http://horebmultimedia.com/Sam5/

In the above links, i have added a set of numbers added in separate containers in each file and u can find the FPS on the top right. The issue is when i mouse over in this Link 1 and click any numbers, as u see the FPS is getting slower & slower, making the world to rotate slower on the left side.

While on this link, Link 2, I added only one mouse over and 5 mouse over, but there is not much difference in FPS, why it lags so much when i have 37 containers. I can give my code if u need to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I had a rough look at your code, but digging through an entire project is not a fantastic way to debug an optimization problem.

The first thing to consider is if you have `mouseOver` enabled on your stage, I would recommend a liberal use of `mouseChildren=false` on interactive elements, and `mouseEnabled=mouseChildren=false` on anything not interactive. The rollover could be a big cause, as it requires everything to be drawn 20 times per second (in your usage). Text and vectors can be expensive to redraw.

```
// Non-interactive elements (block all mouse interactions)
element.mouseEnabled = element.mouseChildren = false;

// Interactive elements (reduce mouse-checking children individually)
element.mouseChildren = false;
```

If they don't change, you might consider caching text elements, or button graphics. I think I saw some caching in the source - but its generally a good thing to consider.

--

With that said, debugging optimization can be tough.. If removing all the buttons brings your performance up, consider how your buttons are being constructed, and what their cost is. 
* Mouse over is expensive
* Vectors and text can be expensive
* Caching can help when used right, but can be expensive if it happens too often.
* Review what is happening on tick(). Sometimes, code is running constantly, which doesn't need to.

--

A few other notes:

- This does not do what you think: `_oButton.off("mousedown");` -- You need to pass the result of the `on()` call. If you are just cleaning up, call `_oButton.removeAllEventListeners()`.
- You don't need to set the cursor on `mouseover`. The cursor will only change when it rolls over -- so just set it once, and then get rid of your `buttonover` stuff.
- It might make sense to just extend EventDispatcher for your custom classes, which gives you things like the `on()` method, which supports a `data` param. I might recommend this in place of your `addEventListener` stuff in `CTextButton`
- Note that RAF does not support a framerate property (it just uses the browser's RAF rate, which is usually 60fps). Use `createjs.Ticker.timingMode` instead of the deprecated `useRAF`.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thank you Bro.Lanny. All things u answered helped me to improve better. Also i use for loop for accessing the containers. Does this too slow up the frame rate. Or is it better we call the class to create button. By this way for loop can be avoided right. Please give ur suggestions.